# Cmake Visual Studio - File created at place of output folder

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, cmake

When I build my library I change output path using

`set_target_properties(${target}
        PROPERTIES
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG
        ${OUTPUT_PATH}
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE
        ${OUTPUT_PATH}
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
        ${OUTPUT_PATH}
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG
        ${OUTPUT_PATH}
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE
        ${OUTPUT_PATH}
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
        ${OUTPUT_PATH}
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG
        ${OUTPUT_PATH}
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE
        ${OUTPUT_PATH}
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
        ${OUTPUT_PATH}
    )`

But when I launch my `cmake ..` a file is created at place of OUTPUT_PATH. This file as the build_type name (Release or Debug).

This blocks my build because when I want to build the target, Visual Studio give me the MSB3191 error because a file exist at place of OUTPUT_PATH so he cannot create the output folder.

Anyone know how to make it create in a other directory ?

PS : The first line of the file is `MZ\220^@^C^@^@^@^D^@^@^@\377\377^@^@\270^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^P^A^@^@^N^_\272^N^@\264   \315!\270^AL\315!This program \
cannot be run in DOS mode.^M^M`

Comment: That looks like an executable. What does your full CMakeLists.txt look like? Any FILE commands, perhaps?

Comment: @Botje My project is big and have a lot of subdirectory. But you maybe help me a lot. I move .dll in output path with file is it possible that the dll get renamed by CMake with the output folder name after copying and before build target ?

Comment: @Botje It was my dll.